# Marklogic DLS document permission is not set properly?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have defined 2 Roles in my MarkLogic database

- TestRole1
- TestRole2

I am setting permissions on the managed document `/test.xml` using

```
dls:document-set-permissions(
   "/test.xml",
   (
     xdmp:permission("TestRole1", "read"),
     xdmp:permission("TestRole2", "read"),
     xdmp:permission("TestRole2", "update")
   )
)
```

After this when I am checking permission on the document, I see that TestRole2 has only read permission not update permission.

```
dls-internal=update
dls-internal=read
TestRole1=read
TestRole2=read
```

Please Help

Comment: 2 thoughts that may help you : 1) How are you checking document permissions? Perhaps its not being done correctly. 2) Do you have any triggers set in your database? If so, is it possible one of those is setting permissions after every update?

Comment: I am checking permission using `xdmp:document-get-permissions("/test.xml")` which return role-id and capabitility.